# Как написать подобие ChatGPT

Tags: python

Коллеги, не подскажите как написать(обучить) модель - подобие ChatGPT, притом желательно чтобы это была именно форма вопрос-ответ, а не как это сделано в Балаболе или GPT 3 - обычным дополнением.
Возможно где-то уже есть такие модели, но их нужно лишь обучать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону [готовых](https://github.com/acheong08/ChatGPT) api. Вам лишь нужно обратится к ним и вывести данные в свое приложение. Написать такое вы вряд ли сможете.

Comment: api - это будет не так объемно, так как проект учебный, возможно все-таки есть какие-то модели, обученные на начальном уровне